# When does high-speed rail between Seville and Granada begin?

Tags: trains, spain, high-speed-rail

Several tourism books and web sites state that high-speed rail service will begin in Andalusia in the first half of 2016. I suppose like most rail projects it won't meet the promised opening date, but does anyone know?

According to the guide, journey time for Seville-Granada will be halved.

**UPDATE 2019:** Spanish Wikipedia indicates "En servicio (26/06/2019)".

Comment: If you're searching for news, it's called the Antequera-Granada HSL rather than Seville/Sevilla-Granada. [Contracts were only signed in June 2014](http://www.globalrailnews.com/2014/06/02/adif-awards-antequera-granada-hsl-contracts/) and [the Spanish Wikipedia page for the line](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnea_de_alta_velocidad_Antequera-Granada#Estado_de_las_obras) indicates it's still under construction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That project was meant to be finished on 2014, delayed to 2015 and finally  to 2016. It's uncertainly until now if it's going to be finished on this half of semester as they promise to (again).

[This is the last new I could find](http://www.diariovasco.com/sociedad/201601/02/fomento-inaugurara-granada-acabar-20160103003105-v.html), and It says that they will open up the station without even finishing the rails (sigh). Probably it's going to take more time as always.

PS: It also says that the construction is paralized therefore It's almost certain that won't be inaugurate on time.

Answer (score 5):

Last news says it should be ready for passengers in the first half of 2017 (last paragraph): http://www.laopiniondemalaga.es/malaga/2016/05/03/ave-granada-afronta-fase-final/846839.html.

The last comment you got is right, one half is Granada-Antequera and the other Antequera-Sevilla... not sure how that will play out though.

Comment: Went by bus from Seville to Granada earlier this very day! Passed over some train works. Just dirt, no track. Anyway, 2017 too late for this trip!

Answer (score 5):

[According to the Railway Gazette](https://www.railwaygazette.com/europe/granada-joins-the-ave-network/48776.article), it opened 2019-06-25.